# What denomination is Kemp?

Tags: being-human, religion

In [*Being Human*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1349938/) (the original British series) season 2, what Christian denomination does Kemp (and presumably his partners) belong to? I seem to recall him being described as Catholic, but that was a non-authoritative statement by another character (George?). However, in a flashback, we see the murder of, in all probability, his wife, which would make him Anglican or Protestant.

Are there conclusive clues? Or is there no answer, possibly [on purpose](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhereTheHellIsSpringfield)?

Comment: FYI: there are married Catholic priests. It involves Anglican or Orthodox parishes with married priests converting to Catholicism.

Comment: @freiheit Or priests in some former Eastern block countries, but none of these are plausible in this context, except perhaps Kemp having converted to Catholicism (but this wasn't mentioned or hinted at that I recall, and it would have been worth a mention if it was part of the plot).

Comment: I believe "former Eastern block" means "Orthodox". But more importantly, the lines between Anglican and Catholic are a bit blurry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Catholic

Comment: http://abcnews.go.com/WNT/Pope/story?id=677904#.Tv0h_yNWrH8 -- married catholic priest is fairly plausible.

Comment: Or maybe the writers were just confused about the difference between Anglican and Catholic. The outfits look pretty much the same.

Comment: Yes the lines between Anglican and Catholic are blurred, but no-one in the UK would describe an Anglican priest/vicar/rector as a Catholic if they were not a Roman Catholic.  If he has been described as a Catholic and has a wife then he is one of the many Anglo-Catholics that converted to being Roman-Catholics when the Anglican church began to allow woman priests.

Answer (score 4):

Kemp is definitely an Anglican priest; he has a wife and children, and in the 'church sequence' he wears the style of surplice common in the church of England; with a green stole (indicating it took place in 'ordinary time - i.e not in Lent/Advent/Christmas/Easterdide or some other festival).

If I were writing the scene, I'd have had Kemp actually celebrating the Eucharist (Mass, Holy Communion - different words for the same sacrament), rather than simply reading the narrative of the last supper.

I am an Anglican priest (happily one whose ministry is to date untroubled by vampires, LOL), and what I can tell you is that some parishes and priests are indistinguishable from Roman Catholic ones, and that many Anglicans will refer to themselves as 'Catholic' - but not 'Roman Catholic'. And of course, it is not impossible in Kemp's back-story that he was ordained as an RC priest, but later switched to the Anglican Church, and subsequently married; there are plenty of examples of this, as well as Anglican clergy converting to Rome.

It's funny as a clergyman, I do pick up on little things like the vestments, etc, and how, sometimes, TV and film companies get it wrong. Sometimes very much so, but its only a few churchgeeks like me who notice.

Being Human did get it right; if the service was a Communion, then Kemp is dressed in a way that many Anglican priests would; Cassock, Surplice, and Stole in the appropriate liturgical colour for the season. Most of us, and especially  in the more Anglo-Catholic end, wear the same Eucharistic vestments as RC clergy - alb, stole, and chasuble, but the way in which Kemp is dressed, assuming the service is a Eucharist, would indicate that his churchmanship was 'middle of the road', rather than full-on Anglo Catholic. Of course, he is correctly vested of Evensong & Sermon, and I think that this is what the service is, in the episode.

Anyway, just wanted to comment, and I am so enjoying the series; a wonderful way to chill, after Sunday services and duties are finished.

Comment: apologies for typos - no edit window!!

Comment: Very few typos actually, refreshing to see. For future reference, we discourage signatures, you can put it in your profile. People can see it there and once you get enough reputation (1,000), people can see it in your [expanded usercard](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) right on the post by hovering over your name.

Comment: Cassock, surplice, liturgical...if I weren't religious already, I convert simply for the cool words.

Comment: Hi guys, thankyou for your welcome, and your comments. Kevin; many apologies for the 'signature' - I know 'ciggies' are discouraged; in fact I gave them up in 2008 (Dammitt, I will never look as cool as the late Mitchell) Having learned that 'siggies' , as well as 'ciggies' are discouraged, I truly repent!!! You seem a friendly bunch, and thankyou again for your welcome!